In this example do the square brackets mean Mexican was the original word and not addict? "the addict [read Mexican]"

... The suppression of traffic in a drug which makes the addict [read Mexican] frequently a dangerous or homicidal maniac.

In this example, do the square brackets mean Mexican was the original word and not addict?

I suspect the original word was addict and the reporter is saying that the original speaker or writer used that word in order to avoid saying Mexican.

Merriam-Webster has this usage under "read": "5 to use as a substitute for or in preference to another word or phrase in a particular passage, text, or version... —often used to introduce a clarifying substitute for a euphemistic or misleading word or phrase: a friendly, read nosy, coworker"

Not to put too fine a point on it, but it seems likely either that the second writer is accusing the first writer of being a racist using euphemisms to avoid being accused of racism, or that the second writer is a racist accusing the first writer of being an apologist.

This comes from page 484 of the technical annex of the 1972 Shafer Commission report, quoting the San Antonio Light from 1931.  I would guess the "[read Mexican]" may have been inserted in 1972 but you would need to find the 1931 publication to be sure.

@StuartF That sounds like an answer. the difficulty with the definition is that it doesn't clarify (to the OP) that the word to be substituted is not a word that was originally there and was replaced, that it is an inference that was made by the person who used "[read 'Mexican']".

Use of '[read Mexican]' in the 1931 San Antonio Light excerpt
As Henry points out in a comment beneath the posted question, the language quoted in the OP's question appears on page 484 of Appendix: Marihuana: A Signal of Misunderstanding: The Technical Papers of the First Report of the National Commission on Marihuana and Drug Abuse (March 1972) [the Shaffer Commission Report], which reads at greater length as follows:

By 1931, the Texas Legislature finally got around to prohibiting possession of marihuana. By now alcohol prohibition had withdrawn any philosophical barrier to making possession illegal. The San Antonio Light reported that:

At last the state legislature has taken a definite step toward suppression of traffic in a dangerous and insanity-producing narcotic easily compounded of a weed (marihuana) indigenous to this section. This newspaper has urged the passage of prohibitory legislation and is gratified that the solons at Austin have acted, even if tardily, in the suppression of traffic in a drug which makes the addict [read Mexican] frequently a dangerous or homicidal maniac (San Antonio Light, 1931).


Austin is the capital of the state of Texas and thus is home to both the governor and the state legislature; hence the wording "the solons at Austin" in the quotation above. The state law in question Sessions Bill 171 passed by the 42nd regular session of the Texas Legislature in 1931 makes no mention of the rationale for criminalizing marijuana possession, but indicates that it passed the State Senate by a vote of 31-0 and passed the State House by a vote of 109-1.
The law's omission of any explanation for why it was needed is quite common in statutory language—both of that time and more recently. Some idea of the impetus for the law may be found in a message from Governor Ross Sterling to the 42nd Legislature on April 15, 1931:

It has been called to my attention that our present laws with reference to traffic in and possession of narcotics are wholly insufficient to protect our citizens from the terrible effects brought about by the use of narcotics.
I am informed that narcotics, and especially marijuana, have been found within the borders of our State. I understand further that the possession of marijuana is not made a violation of the law by our present statutes.
I am further informed that Senate Bill Number 171 is now pending in the Legislature, and those competent to pass upon the subject advise me that this or a similar measure is very much needed in order that we may more effectively fight the traffic in narcotics.
Therefore, I respectively urge that you give to this important matter your earnest consideration, to the end that a helpful measure may become a law at the earliest possible time.

As you can see, there is no mention here of the homicidal mania that marijuana may induce in addicts. The governor describes the nature of the drug's menace only obliquely in the generalized form of an undifferentiated reference to "the terrible effects brought about by the use of narcotics." It bears noticing that the eighteenth amendment to the U.S. Constitution, which banned the manufacture, sale, and transportation of alcoholic beverages, had been ratified in January 1919 and was not repealed until December 1933.
The San Antonio Light journalist/editorialist seems to have pulled a little one-two punch in this article—first by framing the problem as centrally one of suppressing the trade in a drug that generates addicts who frequently become dangerous or homicidal maniacs (not normally an either/or pairing), and second by explaining to the politically or ethnically obtuse that "addict" is just the newspaper's polite way of saying "Mexican." In effect, the Light article is parenthetically asserting that marijuana addicts are usually—if not always—of Mexican heritage.

Use of '[read X]' as a form of clarification and as a rhetorical device
More generally, the form "word or phrase [read other word or phrase]" may appear in at least two very different contexts. One context involves clarifying the intended meaning of the word or phrase preceding the parenthetical in a situation in which that wording, as used, is unintentionally ambiguous or incorrect.
For example, Bryan Garner, Gardner's Modern American Usage, third edition (2009) regularly uses a "[read X]" parenthetical interpolation to indicate a corrected version of quoted language, as here:

"In his forward [read foreword] to Delgado's book, Andrew Hacker defends the storytelling movement." Jeffrey Rosen, "The Blood and the Crits," New Republic, 9 Dec. 1996, at 27.

The second context in which the form "word or phrase [read: other word or phrase]" may appear involves a rhetorical strategy of editorializing by quoting or paraphrasing a source or title and then replacing a key part of that text with the writer's interpretation/translation of it. For example, from "Exposed: The Video the Turkish Dictator Doesn't Want You to See," in Israel Today (October 31, 2019):

Recently, Turkish President (read: Dictator) Recep Tayyip Erdogan used his appearance before the UN General Assembly to rail against Israel and its “oppression” of the Palestinian Arabs.

And from Zak Doffman, "Why We Should Fear China's Emerging High-Tech Surveillance State," in Forbes (October 28, 2018):

Big Brother’s masterplan is ‘Sharp Eyes’, an ambitious (read fanciful) nationally integrated surveillance scheme, connecting government and private sector cameras and sensors, loaded with facial recognition, video analytics and AI. ‘Sharp Eyes’ will detect crime, control access and secure commerce.
...
Just think about the math. Tracking just 10 million of China’s 1.4 billion people in a facial recognition scheme would require daily probability combinations per typical CCTV camera stretching to ten zeros. In reality, standoff systems are loaded with relatively small watch lists of people of interest. Even here, unless they're limited to narrow geographies, they become mathematically unwieldy (read impossible).
...
More than $1 billion of surveillance technology projects were awarded to Hikvision and Dahua for those projects in Xinjiang. This includes securing re-education (read internment) camps, monitoring visitors to mosques, and multiple safe city schemes.

As the San Antonio Light excerpt from 1931 indicates, this rhetorical device is nothing new. What makes it appealing to some writers is that it not only tells readers how to understand a particular instance of the word or phrase being replaced, but also may suggest to readers that they should make the same proposed word substitution any time they see the word used in a similar setting. It is in this light (so to speak) that we can see the San Antonio newspaper's "addict = Mexican" equivalence in the full measure of its vileness.

Yes, this brings out the subtleties of this expression, which are lost if it is treated as a mere clarification. It should perhaps be added that the phrase is sometimes used to express the views of the author who inserts the read-remark (and not the views of the author of the original expression), and sometimes to make explicit how the expression was intended by the original author and likely to be understood by the original audience (whose views one may not share).

Thesaurus.com gives an overview of the main ways in which square brackets are used:

In general, square brackets are used much less often than parentheses
in writing. Most of the time, they are used to alter or provide
additional context to quotes.

This is a very broad definition. Often, a writer will add an explanatory synonym to the original:

The two lovers osculated [kissed].

Sometimes, the improved version is just substituted:

The two lovers [kissed].

Here, [read Mexican] most probably means

[the author suppresses the fact that the addict is highly probably Mexican, for whatever reason, and merely uses 'addict'].

As Stuart says, 'read' is used to indicate the clarifying substitution.
